# Developing Kernels to support Multiple CPUs

Tags: linux, multithreading, operating-system, kernel, multicore

I am looking to get into operating system kernel development and figured my contribution would be to extend the [SANOS](http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/) operating system in order to support multiple core machines. I have been reading books on operating systems (Tannenbaum) as well as studying how BSD and Linux have tackled this challenge but still am stuck on several concepts.

1. Does SANOS need to have more sophisticated scheduling algorithms when it runs on multiple CPUs or will what is currently in place work fine?
2. I know that it is a good idea for threads to have affinity to a core that they were started on, but is this handled via scheduling or by changing the implementation of how threads are created?
3. What would need to be considered such that SANOS could run on a machine with hundreds of cores? From what I can tell, BSD and Linux at best only support a maximum of a dozen of cores.

Comment: Could you amalgamate your SANOS questions, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reading material is good. SO no problems there. Also take a peek at the CS downloadable lectures on operating system design from Stanford.

1. The scheduling algorithm may need to be more sophisticated. This depends on the types of applications running and how greedy they are. Do they yield themselves or are they forced to. That kind of thing. This is more a question of what your processes want, or expect. A RTOS will have more complex scheduling than a desktop.
2. Threads should have an affinity to one core, because 2 threads in one process can execute in parallel ... but not at the same real-time on the same core. Putting them on different cores allows them to really-run-in-parallel. Also caching can be optimized for core affinity. This is really a mix of your thread implementation and scheduler. The sched may want to ensure threads are started at the same time on cores, rather than ad-hoc to reduce the amount of time threads wait on eachother and things. If your thread library is user-space, maybe it assigns core, or lets the scheduler decide based on capacity or recent deaths.
3. Scalability is often a kernel limit (which can be arbitrary). In Linux, if I recall, the limits are due to static sizing of arrays that hold CPU information structs in the scheduler. Hence they are a fixed size. This can be changed by recompiling the kernel. Most good scheduling algorithms will support a very large number of cores. As your core or processor count gets higher, you need to be careful that you don't fragment a processes execution too much. If a program has 2 threads, try and schedule them in close-time-proximity because causation may exist (through shared data) between them.

You also need to decide how your threads are implemented, and how a process is represented (be it heavy or lightweight) in the kernel. Are threads kernel managed? user-space managed? These things all have an impact on scheduler design. Look at how POSIX threads are implemented in various operating systems. There is just so much for you to think about :)

**in short** there are not really any straight-cut answers to where the logic does, or should reside. It is all down to design, application expectation, time-constraints (on the programs) and so on.

Hope this helps, I am not an expert here however.